# Convert array 3 dimensions data into functional data in r

Tags: r

i have an array with dimension [ 128, 64, 1140 ], and i want to convert this array into functional data object,
this is the function :

```
for (i in 1:dim(sst2)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(sst2)[2]) {
    tmpfdd <- Data2fd(argvals = 1140,
                    y = sst2[i, j,],
                    basisobj = create.fourier.basis(nbasis = 15))
  }
}
```

when i run this program, i get this error :

```
Error in argvalsySwap(argvals, y, basisobj) : 
dimensions of 'argvals' and 'y' must be compatible;
dim(argvals) = 1; dim(y) = 1140
```

Comment: y has dim 1140, so argvals needs to have dim of 1140. As is, argvals has dim 1. argvals = 1140, which is the value of the dim of y. You'll need something like argvals = 1:dim(sst2)[3] , which has dim of 1140, though the assignment will depend on what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I have already tried what you have indicated, but i get another error : ```{r}
for (i in 1:dim(sst2)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(sst2)[2]) {
    tmpfdd <- Data2fd(argvals = 1:dim(sst2)[3],
                    y = sst2[i, j,],
                    basisobj = create.fourier.basis(nbasis = 15))
  }
}
```  when i run this program, i get this error :  ```{r}
Error in argvalsySwap(argvals, y, basisobj) : 
Neither 'argvals' nor 'y' are contained in basisobj$rangeval
```